# Registering a subfolder with bower

Tags: bower

Is there a way to inclusively specify which files I want served when a user does a

`bower install MY_PACKAGE`

Right now, there is a `ignore` array where I can add the files which I want excluded. There is a [proposal](https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/1015) to do something like this, but I want to know if someone out there has already hacked his way into doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the source control facility of your choice, such as:

- Git tag
- Git branch
- Subversion revision

to distribute an artifact ID rather than the package name.